# Python JSON parse_float=decimal.Decimal not working

Tags: python, json

I have a string with a floating point number in it, but I can't get JSON to load it as a decimal.

```
x = u'{"14": [4.5899999999999999, "susan"]}'
json.loads(x, parse_float = decimal.Decimal)
```

This returns:

```
{u'14': [Decimal('4.5899999999999999'), u'susan']}
```

Any idea how I can make it into the actual "4.59"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define a function that performs whatever rounding you desire, then uses the altered string to build the `Decimal`.  Your current solution does work perfectly well: it just does exactly what you tell it to, i.e., use the entire string, as opposed to what you desire (and have not told either the code, or us;-).

E.g.:

```
>>> def doit(s): return decimal.Decimal(str(round(float(s), 2)))
... 
>>> json.loads(x, parse_float=doit)
{u'14': [Decimal('4.59'), u'susan']}
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. That number isn't 4.59, it's 4.589999999999999999, as far as the json parser knows. You'd need to add some more complicated logic that rounds numbers like that, as a wrapper around decimal.Decimal.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is over a decade later, but just to refine the answer from Alex Martin a bit for anyone coming across this as I did on Google. We can simplify his function to:

```
json.loads(x, parse_float=lambda x: round(decimal.Decimal(x),2))
```

The reason is that the value passed into the `parse_float` callable by `json.loads` is already a `str`. Also, this code would not truncate the input value at 64 bits as his would (parsing to a float first will truncate at 64 bit precision).

Obviously, you could use a function rather than a lambda too. I just used the lambda here for brevity.